# JBoss EAP 6.2GA Managed Domain Exploded-Deployment

Tags: java, jboss

Is there a way to deploy exploded war file for Web Application in JBoss EAP 6.2 GA Domain manage mode. 
Since I looked through its contents folder inside tmp folder.There is extracted content of my web skeleton,When I changed something it never affected to my site.

I'm currently develop on JDK 7 with Netbean 7.4 and Windows 7

Comment: Sincerely you should use "standalone" mode as domain mode is "reserved" to large-scaling infrastructure.

Comment: i think u should have a file with the same name as your exploded war file but with the extension dodeploy in your deployment folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can deploy exploded application using CLI command in domain mode.

Use following CLI command to deploy application

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /deployment=version.war:add(runtime-name="test.war", content=[{"path"=>"/path/to/test.war","archive"=>false}])
```

Please, Make sure the exploded directory is available to all instances in the server group / Host where you want to deploy to. E.g. *"/path/to/test.war"* must be a valid path on all instances.

**Deploy the application on a specific server group**

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] deploy --name=test.war --server-groups=test-group
```

**Note :** That the *--name=test.war* must have a correct deployment type extension (.war, .ear, etc.) as this is how JBoss EAP determines the deployment type.